# Vagrant - Chef - templatefile check

Tags: templates, chef-infra, vagrant

how do I get it out to test whether there is a template file.

I want to load the webserver default.conf.erb only if there is no other appropriate config there.

I had thought so, but without success.

```
template "#{node[:nginx][:dir]}/sites-available/#{host_name}.loc.conf" do
        variables attribs

        if File.exists? ("/templates/default/#{host_name}.conf.erb")
            source "#{host_name}.conf.erb"
        else
            source "default.conf.erb"
        end

        notifies :reload, "service[nginx]"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a concept (under the label of [File Specificity](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_templates.html#file-specificity)) is already implemented in chef.

Just place your file in `templates/host-#{host_name}/` instead of `templates/default/`.